# TypeError: 'ObjectApiResponse' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, elasticsearch, flask

I am making an api in python to link it with elasticsearch but when executing it, it generates an error on line 23 res['ST'] = search_term which translates as 'ObjectApiResponse' object does not support item assignment, I appreciate your help and collaboration

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import os

os.chdir('/home/ambu/Documents/search')
app: Flask = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
es = Elasticsearch("http://127.0.0.1:9200")


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('search.html')


@app.route('/search/results', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def request_search():
    search_term = request.form["input"]
    res = es.search(
        index='data_example4',
        body={
            "query": {"match": {"content": search_term}},
            "highlight": {"pre_tags": ["<b>"], "post_tags": ["</b>"], "fields": {"content": {}}}})
    res['ST'] = search_term
    for hit in res['hits']['hits']:
        hit['good_summary'] = '….'.join(hit['highlight']['content'][1:])
        return render_template('results.html', res=res)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('127.0.0.1', debug=True)
```

Thank you for your help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The were some changes to the ElasticSearch Python Client from version 7 to 8.  One of those changes is instead of the API returning a raw dict, it is now a structured ApiResponseObject.  But you can use the update method to add to this object.

```
res.update({"ST": search_term})
```

For further infomation you can see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/migration.html